# Passar parâmetro entre duas JSPs

Tags: jsp, servlet

Tenho a página final.jsp e saida.jsp.
Na página final.jsp eu mando o parâmetro assim:

```
<form action="saida.jsp">
        <input type="hidden" name="informal" value="${documento.stringInformais}">
        <button type="submit" value="Enviar">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

e a partir dai eu não sei como devo receber o parâmetro em `saida.jsp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode obter o parâmetro na página `saida.jsp` através de EL:

```
${param.informal}
```

Inclusive dentro de uma tag `jstl`

```
<c:out value="${param.informal}" />
```

Ou usar scriptlets (que devem ser evitados):

```
<%= request.getParameter("informal") %>
```